# What's the pricing for a big concurrency of requests App hosting in Google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, aws-cli

I am in a project to make a web app and we want to host in Google cloud but we can't specify the price because we don't  know which services to choose, it's a big app with 18 microservices and a lot of requests per day(let's say 70000 users) can someone explain to me how to get the pricing for the app engine? Or In any other cloud service?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The website explicitly deals with questions related to programming. You might get some help by asking this question on Google Support Forums.

Comment: Potentially of interest - same considerations apply to GCP (and other cloud providers as well), not only to AWS: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/how-much-it-will-cost-for-aws-for-deploying-a-inventory-management-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to predict the price you are asking for in a detailed way. It depends on several factors:

- Availability: If you want 24x7 service or not.
- Traffic: Egress traffic, related to requests number.
- Resources: CPU, memory etc.

If those requests aren't using much CPU or memory the price is going to be cheaper.

A good idea would be to make a prototype in App Engine standard, using "always free usage limits" and see how it performs {1}.

You also can use Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator to get a better idea {2}.

{1}: https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/always-free-usage-limits

{2}: https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/